# QT Post, the user data is send in another TCP packet, not in one POST http

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp

QT Post, the user data is send in another TCP packet, not in one POST http.

Using ethernet trace tool to check QT post, found the QT sent out a POST http first but not contained user data, then later another TCP packet sent out with user data but not POST HTTP.

Do you know how to force the QT to send all user data in one POST HTTP?

Many Thanks!

```
QUrl urlDigital("http://data.service.com");
QNetworkAccessManager *sfsmanager;
QNetworkRequest sfsrequest;

sfsrequest.setUrl(urlDigital);
sfsrequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,QVariant("multipart/form-data"));
sfsrequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, pstring.size());
sfsreply = sfsmanager->post(sfsrequest, pstring);
```

Comment: Why is that a problem? TCP's a streaming protocol, you can't rely on packet boundaries being maintained at all on the receiver.

Comment: Yes, but compared the Chrome Poster, the Chrome Poster will contains the user data with the POST HTTP. Is there any trick there?

Comment: Like @Mat said: you cannot expect the request to be contained within a single packet. This is how TCP works. If you need it to behave differently you should maybe explain the reason behind it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, the idea is use QT to generate a similar HTTP POST as Chrome Poster done. But looks like the QNetworkmanager make the HTTP post not fully comply the HTTP POST protocol, maybe my understanding is not right in the protocol part. But how server can handle different POST then?

Comment: HTTP uses TCP for delivery and is thus agnostic to packet boundaries. If a request is small, then  header and payload can be in the same packet, but they don't need to be. Even the request header itself can be spread over multiple packets. The server must just read the HTTP request header (that is until CRLF CRLF) and then must look into the header to determine how much bytes the body will have. Then read until the complete body is done. This is because TCP is a stream protocol which unlike a datagram protocol like UDP has no inherent record boundary.

Comment: Is it possible to force QT to generate one HTTP POST? In my usage, enclose all user data into one packet is preferred.

Comment: It's not really in application's domain to decide or care about how TCP/IP *stream* is divided into *IP* packets, so practical answer is "no".